# scanr3: Why does step, a binary operator, accept [zero] as a parameter?

Tags: haskell

[Lists_III Solutions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Solutions/Lists_III)

To do: Write your own definition of scanr using foldr.

After making my function I studied the book's solution and saw that step' calls step which gets its x argument from step' which was called with two list arguments: [zero] and xs. Then step' calls step with a list x and a number (head xs).   Oddly, if you replace [zero] with a number, like plain zero by removing the square brackets, the program compiles but does not run.  It actually wants a list.  Why is that?

```
--Implement scanr (+) 0 [1,2,3] = [6,5,3,0]: My scnrf
scnrf   f acc  []     =  [acc]
scnrf   f acc  y@(x:xs)   =  foldr f  acc y :  scnrf  f  acc  xs

--with fold: Haskell book's solution
scanr3 step zero xs = foldr step' [zero] xs
    where step' x xs = (step x (head xs)):xs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is that? As far as I understood your question, the expression types (in your words, it compiles) because it infers that `zero` is a list of something (why? [1]).

```
-- this expression types!
scanr3 step zero xs = foldr step' zero xs
  where step' x xs = (step x (head xs)):xs
```

Recall that `zero` now should be a list:

```
Prelude> scanr3 (+) [0] [1,2,3]
[6,5,3,0]
```

but can't be an `Int` as you expected:

```
Prelude> scanr3 (+) 0 [1,2,3]

<interactive>:18:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num [a], Num a) => [a]
```

[1]: Because, when the definition reaches the base case of `foldr`, that is, `foldr step' zero []`, it will be substituted by `zero`, and replacing this expression in

```
where step' x xs = (step x (head xs)):xs
```

where `xs = zero`, is equivalent to

```
where step' x zero = (step x (head xs)):zero
```

So, `zero` should be a list, because it is expected to be on the right hand side of `:`.

Comment: After re-reading this response many times two questions come to mind: 1) If step' returns a list, how does foldr accept that as its first argument? 2) The arguments to step' are x  and xs. foldr calls step' with zero and [].  How did the  zero wind up as the second argument in the left hand side of your last line of code when it was called with zero as the first argument?

Comment: 1) `step'` is a function, not a list. Check `foldr`'s type: `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. So `step'` takes something of type `a` and also something of type `b`, which is a list. So `b` has the form `[c]`, for another type `c`. Is that clear?

Comment: 2) Let's recap `foldr` equations: `foldr op z [] = z` and `foldr op z (x:xs) = op x (foldr op z xs)`

`foldr` eventually will expand into this expression: `op x1 (op x2 (op x3 (... (op xn z))...)`

change `op` to `step'` and `z` to `zero` and you will see why `zero` winds up as the second argument. I can explain this better in the solution if you want.

Comment: I appreciate your offer to explain this better, but I hope that won't be necessary because I feel you've explained it thoroughly.  It now remains for me to study it until I understand it.  Thank you.

Comment: OK, I now get it :)  After getting your initial answer, I did copy the definition of foldr  to my work file.  However, I did not take the trouble to unwind it.  Had I done so, I would've seen that zero in the base case, which is usually a number, but in this case, in order to agree with step', it had to be a list [zero]. (Honestly I'm not sure I would made the connection though.)  But by following your comments it became obvious how the [zero] became the second argument in step'.  For me this has been a major lesson on how to analyze these functions.

Comment: I'm glad you got it! Yes, it could be a bit tough in the beginning, but once you understand those types you'll start use these high order patterns naturally ;)